# Using a single "ajax loader image" in different places in a webpage

Tags: jquery

I have a page with more than 20 different sections, each of which can be updated via AJAX. I need to show an AJAX loader right next to the field while it is being updated. On page load I am loading one loader image in each of these 20+ sections and hiding them, and in the the beforesend function I am using .show().

The problem here is 20+ img tags means 20+ HTTP requests.... which is very bad. I was wondering if there was any way to load just one loader per page and position it wherever and whenever needed !!!

The solution I could think of so far is to get the position of the container by .offset() and set the position of loader with this value. 
Kindly suggest me any better way to do it. I have loaders of 2 different sizes (loader-bg.gif and  loader-sm.gif) used in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

```
function putIconHere(clicked_element){
    var my_icon =   document.getElementById('my_loading_icon');
    clicked_element.parentElement.insertBefore(my_icon,clicked_element);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<button onclick="putIconHere(this);/*your other onclick*/">Load</button>

<img src="loader-sm.gif" id="my_loading_icon" />
```

Comment: your solution suits my requirement the most. I now have both my loaders placed in my master page and I have declared a class "wait-append" in all the places wherever I want the loader to be visible. In my on click events I am doing something like this - $('.loader-sm').appendTo('.wait-append'); I mean actually I use id to append to a particular element. Everything's fine, but is there any way to destroy the loader on success !! Tried .remove () but it destroyed the image permanently...

Comment: You're on the right path. Since we're essentially just moving the same loader around the page, I would only use `.hide()` to 'remove' the loader.  But by doing that, you then have to use `.show()` after `.appendTo()` to show it again.

Comment: yeah that's what I am doing now...thanks for saving so many http requests for me ;-)

Comment: Hey I need one more favor from you, have you ever worked with x-editable plugin !! if yes, please take a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191282/using-x-editable-to-make-multiple-fields-editable-in-an-existing-bootstrap3-hori

Answer (score 1):

Well in that case you could use `.ajaxStart()/.ajaxStop()` methods for a single page:

```
#ajxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; opacity:0.7; background:black; z-index:1;}
#progress{position:absolute; width:400px; height:200px; margin:-100px 0 0 -200px; background:url('path/to/loading/gif') center center no-repeat; z-index:2;}

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('<div />',{id:"ajxOverlay"}).appendTo('body');
    $('<div />',{id:"progress"}).appendTo('body');
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#ajxOverlay, #progress').remove();
});
```