# Using X-editable to make multiple fields editable in an existing bootstrap3 horizontal form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I am using Bootstrap3 for my frontend development and PHP for backend processing. I am trying to use x-editable plugin in one of my pages(user profile), where I have tens of forms with editable fields. Each form is meant to accept different details of a registered user and hence has all types of inputs(text,date,number,email etc.).

My requirements are:

1. Say I have 10 different segments, each having a form to accept a particular set of information [ex. Basic Details or Contact details or Hobbies etc.]. I want to have a single **Edit** button for one form to make all its fields  editable, a single **Save** button to save updated data(after validating them) and a **Cancel** button.
2. I want to send few hidden fields along with the form.
3. I already have a highly customized Validation plugin() working very well for me, can I use that instead of the built in support? Because, I have made a lot of changes in that plugin to suit my requirement, I don't want to go through that cycle again.

Here is a demo of what I want

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Contact Information <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button></h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required max-length="50" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
    </div>  
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
    </div>   
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="number">Phone Number:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" required max-length="15" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
      </div>
    </div>   
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/mrrL6njw/) of this form. I would be of great help if someone can make atleast x-editable work for this.

P.S.: I am new to JSFiddle, so I did not know how to make the basic editable work there. next time I will post a fiddle of exactly what I have tried and is working instead of basic html. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why so X-editable then? Having just one button to save all the fields use simple form and submit it over AJAX.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak: I could do that, but on click of a "single" Edit button I want to make all fields editable, and then on click of a "single" Save button I wanna save them

Comment: I know, but still can't understand why you want to overload your app with plugins which you don't really need for (or need just a very tiny part of its functionality)? Use plugins when you're going to take most of their advantages (besides, X-editable is not designed for what you want it to do). Don't use them for something you can code with just few lines. Just a very quick example - http://jsfiddle.net/u83gse13/

Comment: @Artur Filipiak: Thank you so much for saving my day man. Since I am new in this field I was afraid that I'd miss out on something if I try to do it on my own and also, there are more than 20 segments each having close to 10 fields where this functionality needs to be implemented, hence decided to use the plugin. But you have shown me how simple it is. Since I already have a perfectly functional validation plugin and server side validation in place as well, I will definitely go ahead with your solution. Thanks a lot bro. By the way, great job with your website, loved it.